# Creacion de informe en ireport con valores nulos

Tags: java, ireport

estoy generando un informe en ireport con netbeans y java..la fuente de datos que estoy usando es una clase datasource la cual al momento de llamar al reporte va con los datos correctos pero al ejecutar los valores se muestran nulos...acá está la llamada al reporte

JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr, parametros, datasource);

Comment: Te aparece algún tipo de error en consola al generar el reporte?

Comment: Agrega todo el còdigo por favor y agrega si se muestra un error. Que es jr ya que no puedo saber que constructor usas https://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JasperFillManager.html ?

Comment: Ya lo solucioné...la verdad no se exactamente cual era el problema...hice de nuevo el reporte y pasó bien ..gracias de todas formas